# NFC tag redirect to download app from Play Store

Tags: android, nfc, ndef

I developed a NFC app in android. How do i do if i want,once the user scan the tag,the tag redirect the user to playstore to download my app if the user haven't install my app. If user already installed my app it should open the app instead redirect to play store. Any advice or link is highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An application demo which implements your requested functionality is available [here](http://www.creativebloq.com/android/getting-started-nfc-android-5126313).

Comment: How we do for version below 4.0.?

Comment: I don't understand. that link goes to a magazine subscription. What does it have to do with answering the question? Do I have to subscribe to the magazine to find out?

Comment: @BigBoy1337: that link, after one year and a half, is changed. updated.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Android Application Records at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html#aar

Comment: How we do for version below 4.0.?